# Angular 4 export enum type from library/dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular-library

I want to make a library to use in my Angular 4 applications, and for some business I will do on it I have an `enum` that the applications will need to use later.
Problem is, I declare the enum like this in `my-enum.ts`:

```
export enum MyEnum {
    value1 = 1,
    value2 = 2,
    value3 = 3
}
```

But then, I can't seem to import it from my app when I do the following:

```
import { MyEnum } from 'my-library';
```

How should I proceed to have this correctly?

Comment: Is your library stored in node_modules?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea

Comment: Do you have an index.ts file in the root location of the library?

Comment: Yes. It's content is `export * from './public_api';`

Comment: you have to export also the `enum` as well or you will have to add the relative path to the enum in the import statement like `import { MyEnum } from '../node_modules/my-library/myenum';`

Comment: How do I export it? I thought that by doing `export enum MyEnum { ...}` should have been enough...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153412/discussion-between-bogdan-bogdanov-and-cesard).

Answer (score 6):

If you are writing Angular libraries, you have to export enums with the keyword **const**

```
export const enum <ENUM_NAME>
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue, but I simply forgot to build my library before trying to use the exported enum (`ng build --prod my-library`).